# Setting field values for M2M object in djnago

Tags: python, django, model

I have two models in my application and I am trying to update a M2M field . Django documentation says that it can be done using set() method . But I guess by dealt set() accepts pk of the objects as arguments  and what I want to do is set it using the actual values .

For e.g. I have a client in Clients models named "adam" and I want to set the value for its corresponding M2M field "items_onsale" to ["ac" , "book"]

Below is my code for the models :-

```
from django.db import models


class Client(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mailid = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    items_onsale = models.ManyToManyField('Sinfo', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):  # for displaying the variable correctly.
        return self.fname , self.lname , self.mailid , self.sex , self.age , self.items_onsale


class Sinfo(models.Model):  # data of items put on sale by clients
    iname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    idesc = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)

    def __str__(self):  # for displaying the variable correctly.
        return self.iname
```

What I have tried till now is :-

```
c = Client.objects.get(pk=17)
list=["ac","book"]
c.items_onsale_set(list)
```

And I am getting below error :-

**ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'book'**

I know that there is a way to update it using values but not sure how . The django documentation does suggest using "through_defaults" option but haven't given any such example , so I am quite not sure how to use it  :-

For many-to-many relationships set() accepts a list of either model instances or field values, normally primary keys, as the objs argument.

Use the through_defaults argument to specify values for the new intermediate model instance(s), if needed. You can use callables as values in the through_defaults dictionary and they will be evaluated once before creating any intermediate instance(s).

I am there is a better to achieve this , please let me know .

Comment: There is a typing error , it is :- c.items_onsale.set(list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

through_defaults option works if you have multiple foreign-keys in the same model when using the through option.
in your case, the items_onsale have a direct relationship with the client, use the add function instead of set.

```
c = Client.objects.get(pk=17)
list=["ac","book"]
c.items_onsale.set(list)
```

to

```
 c = Client.objects.get(pk=17)
 list= Sinfo.objects.filter(iname__in=["ac","book"])
 c.items_onsale.add(*list)
```

add() accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, not a list of them.
To expand that list into arguments, use *

Comment: Yes, later I used add() and it worked , although didn't knew about arguments and list part , that helps a lot , thank you .